# Why pass a variable to a function in Python?

Tags: python, variables

I had a code where the author declares some variables for physical constants. And then a function which uses them but not pass this parameters as function arguments.

```
g = 9.81  # gravity (m / s^2)
m = 10    # mass (kg)

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 10)

def f1(x):
    return g * m * x**2

def f2(x):
    return x / m
```

Is it the best way to go or should I pass them as an argument too?

Given that if I do:

```
def f():
    return x + y

x = 1
y = 2
```

When `f()` is called we get:

```
>>> f()
3
```

**Whats is the difference between passing the variable as an argument and using it from the global module's scope?**

```
def f(x, y):
    return x + y

x = 1
y = 2
```

Which leads to:

```
>>> f(x, y)
3
```

Comment: The former is pretty useless if you want to import that function and add anything other than `1 + 2`...

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist If I don't want to import this i will be the same, wont it?

Comment: *Explicit is better than implicit.* Pass the arguments explicitly or you'll have a hard time debugging a seemingly simple code.

Comment: _'this other thing'_ is/are parameters or arguments for the function.

Comment: @JonathonOgden Yes I know, but I mean. Whats is the difference between passing the variable as an argument and using it from the global module's scope?

Comment: @PabloRdrRbl be more specific in your questions then, please. Seems you have answers now to consider.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Globals vs Parameters for Functions with the Same Parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21054775/globals-vs-parameters-for-functions-with-the-same-parameters)

Comment: FWIW, my personal choice would be to make mass a function parameter, but to keep `g` as a global constant. Generally, the names of global constants in Python are in upper case, but I guess `g` is ok here, since it's fairly traditional in physics, and `G` is Newton's universal gravitation constant. But I guess if you want to be pedantic you could use something like `A_G` for this gravitational acceleration constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing it the first way severely hampers the re-usability of your function.

Simple Example:

What if I wanted to see the outcome from of your function when `y=3` when `x` is any of the numbers in `[2, 4, 6]`?

With the first example, you'd need:

```
def f():
    return x + y

results=[]
y = 3
x = 2
results.append(f())

x = 4
results.append(f())

x = 6
results.append(f())

# Or alternatively -- shorter but kind of redundant:
for num in [2, 4, 6]:
    x = num
    results.append(f())
```

With the 2nd option, you can just do this:

```
def f(x, y):
    return x + y

y = 3
x = [2, 4, 6]
results = [f(i,y) for i in x]
```

Now imagine that with much larger numbers of repetitions for use of `f()`.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that this is a scoping issue.  You can read:

http://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html

In your particular case, the former function uses the variables x and y as declared elsewhere in your code.  The latter function uses the local variables x and y.  You could call the latter function to produce a different value (i.e. f(2, 3) would print 5), while the former function will always output x+y for x and y defined elsewhere in your code.

So the first function relies on having x and y be defined elsewhere while the latter defines them internally and avoids confusion with other code, thus we prefer the latter function.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that python doesn't easily allow modifying values outside of the function's scope (in this case you are only reading them, so it works fine).

The better answer is that passing variables is preferred because it is better software design. Global state is having variables accessible to many sections of code without being separated from eachother. Global state is poor design because if one section of your code makes an unexpected change to the state, which suddenly breaks the section of code you are writing, it is very difficult to track down the source of the error.

It is better to properly encapsulate variables to prevent them from leaking anywhere they shouldn't. Passing values is like making a pipe to carry them safely to where they are needed. It also makes tracking bugs easier, because you only need to find the section of code (a function, an object, or maybe the connection to internet) where the program stops working, and you can fix it without learning about what the rest of your code was doing.

Passing arguments also makes it easier to change a function's behaviour by passing it different data. When you need global state, the best way to handle it is to carry variables inside an object, along with well-defined ways to modify them (class methods).

Encapsulation helps programmers manage extremely large and complex systems by making it easy to reason about pieces of those systems. Violating encapsulation is a quick way to make debugging a nightmare, even though it *seems* easier. Why use a function in the first place if you'll pull its guts out like that?

In the example code, the module is small enough that it doesn't need good design. In a bigger project (>50 lines), it's best to apply good design and refactor so that each part is easy to replace and debug as you add features. You'll find that many mathematicians and academic coders are only concerned about the output. To them, coding is a slightly more powerful calculator and they don't often need abstractions.